# Date not accepting Locale in android

Tags: android

i have to give dates in my application in German language. 
So when i make a calendar object i do this:

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.GERMANY);
```

To display the date obtained from the above i do the following using the `SimpleDateFormat` class:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE ddmmyy");
Log.i("the parsed string", sdf.format(gc.getTime());
```

The above should return the name of the day in German, but it is still returning it in English. what do i do?

thank you in advance.

Comment: new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE ddmmyy", Locale.GERMANY).format(gc.getTime())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the Locale in the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE ddmmyy", Locale.GERMANY);
```